# MouseOverFunction() not Working even with Box collider attached

Tags: unity-game-engine

Basically, I want to change the alpha value of color of guiTexture and guiText while is Mouse Held over the head up display on the game screen.

I did the following

- First I put all the `guiTexture` and `guiText` elements in hierarchy by making the empty `GameObject` named `Head up Display`.
- I attached the box colldier with `Head up Display` and attached a script named `HeadUpDisplay`.
- In above mentioned script I called the `void OnMouseOver()` Function. But this function is not working.

Code is attached there.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HeadUpDisplay : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float AlphaColor;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        GUITexture a = GameObject.Find("g_HUD").guiTexture;

        Color textureColor = a.color;
        textureColor.a = AlphaColor;
        a.color = textureColor;

        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            try
            {
                GUIText x = child.GetComponent<GUIText>();
                Color temp = x.font.material.color;
                temp.a = AlphaColor;
                x.font.material.color = temp;
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }
    void OnMouseOver()
    {
        print(gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

I just only want to change the alpha value of color of all `guitexture` and `guitext` contained in hierarchy `Head Up Display` when mouse held or passes over. Thats it !

Please guide me using c# language references only, not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that the OnMouseOver function works in unity, add some debugs, to make sure what its doing, also if OnMouseOver is not working, make your own function for that(limits, and mouse inside that area)

Comment: Can you please help me by representing your suggestions in code I pasted above?